# I would like to ask your a button in the different layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Excuse my English is not good, I would ask why the button in the RelativeLayout is gray in the press, the LinearLayout is no problem

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="add"
        android:text="button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In of relative RelativeLayout, button is failed, in a Linearlayout is normal

Comment: your button code doesnt have an ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a color, it will not go gray.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:background="#4b14b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="add"
        android:text="button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm not that mean....in RelativeLayout  push down not down, in LinearLayout is normal..Why???Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you